# Render HTML tags in Laravel & Vue.js

Tags: html, vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I am developing an application using Laravel & Vue.js. I have some data in database like `Hello <b>world!</b>`. How can I display them as Hello **world!** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `v-html` binding:

```
<p v-html="fromDB"></p>
```

assuming you have a `fromDB` property in your viewmodel like e.g.

```
data() {
  return {
    fromDB: 'Hello <b>world!</b>'
  }
}
```

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2po80169wy

Reference:

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

**Please be aware that this comes with a risk since from your database, `fromDB` can become just about anything, e.g. `<script>console.log('logged')</script>`.**